# Clickable spreadsheet cell to call script with full rights

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to manually send emails according to a row in a Google spreadsheet (order mail for listed article). I've tried a dropdown selection with edit watcher, but a function called by `onEdit` is restricted and can not send emails, even if there is an OK button in a MsgBox that has to be clicked.

If nothing else will serve the purpose I will use a checkbox and a menu entry that processes all lines checked (which is more complicated as the script will have to handle multiple entries).

Best would be a clickable cell within the row, but I don't know how to make `HYPERLINK` calling a function. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do?

Comment: About `But a function called by onEdit is restricted and can not send a mails`, in this case, although I'm not sure about your actual script, how about using the installable OnEdit trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) At that time, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to another name and install it as the installable OnEdit trigger to avoid duplicate executions. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Tanaike.  Name your function something other than `onEdit()` and use an installable trigger.  Go to "Triggers" in Sidebar of AppsScript editor [image: Screenshot1]

Then, set up an trigger for the function.  In the case of the screenshot, I named the function `onMyEdit` and am selecting the `on Edit` trigger.

[image: Screenshot2]

Then, you can use a checkbox which will trigger the script to be run and then clear the checkbox with the script (if desired).

That is how I would set it up.

Here is a sample script:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {

var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;
var col = range.getColumn();
var row = range.getRow();
var value = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),3).getValue();

if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Sheet1") {
  return
}
else {
  if (col == 1 && row > 1) { 


  var html_body =  "This is a test email that includes the value associated with the checkbox  The value is <strong>" +value+ "</strong>.<br><br>"  
                 + "Thank you, <br>"
                 + "So and so <br><br>" //Change to name of sender.
                 + "<em>This email is an automated notification. Please don't reply.</em>"
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xxxxxxx", //Add comma-separated email addresses here
    subject: "Such and such", //Change to subject.
    body: "",
    htmlBody: html_body,
    noReply: true
  });

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var message = "Requested email has been sent." //Change this as desired.
  e.range.uncheck();
  ui.alert(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  
}
}
}
```

**Explanation:**  When checking a checkbox in Sheet1!A2:A, an email will be sent with corresponding row of data in Sheet1!B2:B.  The cells unchecks and a message box pops up letting you know that the email was sent.

Here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet with dialog box after clicking the checkbox in A3.  Popup from Google shows that the email arrived in my inbox.
[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. There is no way to get the triggering cell (as in the simple trigger's argument), I presume? That would make the handling way easier and cause way less runtime than checking all checkboxes each time any edit was entered.

Comment: There is.  See [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) on "Event Objects" here. Share your script if you need help modifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The documentation handles both trigger types alike, but it throws an error. Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ju4oz6x9/1/

Comment: Are you running this code from the script editor?  That will throw an error as there is no event object.  The event object is the actual edit done to the spreadsheet.  When testing code that sends email, I use my own email address, edit the sheet, and then check my email to be sure everything worked correctly.

Comment: No no. The test message above is from the script called by the trigger, of course. Every edit calls the trigger which calls the function, but the argument is obviously not recognised.

Comment: Added sample script with spreadsheet screenshot to the answer.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work for you?

Comment: Now I did. :-) Yes, Your script is working. Thank You very very much. I still couldn't figure out what difference made my script not work. ‍♂️ Must probably be that you overwrite the range (with another "range"). I was directly accessing it by.. ```let activeRow = e.range.getRow();```